# Statistical test to choose features correlated with the target variable

Tags: r, machine-learning, correlation, predictive-models, biostatistics

Every time I have a binary target variable (like gender for example), and I want to choose the features that are the most informative, I use wilcoxon test, since it is only two groups. I do something like this:

```
p = apply(gene_expression_matrix,1,FUN=function(x) wilcox.test(x~metadata$Gender)$p.value)
```

And I can just pick the features according to the p-value.

But now, I have a continuous feature,`age`, as the target variable, and I want to choose the most informative features (I have aroud 11,000 genes and I want to pick only 10 or 15 at most). I cant use wilcoxon of course. What test can I use to do so?

The predictive features are gene expressions (so they are all continuous, named `gene_expression_matrix` in the line of code above). Here is a glimpse:

```
structure(list(EA595454 = c(30.2164549598862, 33.15472982718, 
33.1168668509201, 33.4462790910655, 32.81331, 28.4089, 27.96669, 
31.75017, 30.2672330352574, 34.2580821880517), EA595500 = c(29.6990111629723, 
33.1091846617464, 34.6961953429537, 35.04752533625, 33.23422, 
29.52738, 28.5988, 29.94425, 30.2917090730326, 34.1113435705727
), EA595522 = c(30.1226080040122, 32.4635957373198, 35.1005945051642, 
34.6336450777183, 33.39675, 25.8611, 29.31165, 30.08221, 31.061397352459, 
34.1756092385343), EA595529 = c(32.5465525771926, 32.7013456847345, 
31.6635327751442, 32.9358067514439, 33.45026, 28.00596, 25.99824, 
30.47032, 31.8664285765267, 33.9110874526159), EA595597 = c(31.4361458857461, 
33.4179129770505, 33.9060231563796, 34.5115736452467, 33.0369, 
28.02942, 29.68764, 31.39326, 30.6585915260075, 34.0716769346108
), EA595624 = c(30.4736738817874, 30.8289027505712, 34.5761979693053, 
34.851895627338, 33.3998, 28.04667, 27.32396, 30.56988, 30.6148908548419, 
34.024757317707), EA595632 = c(31.9171369712556, 32.6958971571296, 
33.8183033615801, 34.909149630392, 33.44333, 28.02871, 29.80188, 
29.95182, 29.9633898390567, 34.2902861791278), EA595635 = c(30.9578243452507, 
33.2022811354514, 34.847170680293, 34.6831757047789, 33.16384, 
28.12376, 30.82226, 32.04497, 31.064684305675, 34.9001181983966
), EA595647 = c(32.0170360984064, 33.2667207360548, 33.886907956777, 
33.3616390602848, 31.82716, 28.13823, 31.00259, 31.70645, 32.1868849430291, 
33.4547257007404), EA595654 = c(28.5455213784364, 32.3327903106071, 
34.2575222117395, 34.0760753017882, 32.98319, 29.73313, 28.1375, 
29.2608, 30.6220152928576, 32.9504526897301)), row.names = c("A1BG", 
"ADA", "CDH2", "AKT3", "MED6", "DDTL", "NAALADL1", "SIGLEC14", 
"ACOT8", "ABI1"), class = "data.frame")
```

**Note - The number of samples that I want to predict is above 800, and the values in `gene_expression_matrix` are not normaly distributed (I say this because some tests assume normal distribution).**

Answer (score 0):

Picking features individually by *p*-value as you have been doing is not generally a good approach, for a couple of reasons. First, the *p*-values are very dependent on the particular sample at hand. Your choices might not extend well to new data. Second, that approach misses features that might be important when other features are taken into account.

I you consider `age` to be the continuous outcome variable of interest and you are asking if there is a small number of genes whose expression best predicts `age`, then a standard principled approach would be LASSO. See Chapter 6 of [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/). That returns a  limited number of features, whose number is determined by an adjustable penalty factor, that together are associated with outcome. The coefficient estimates for the features are appropriately penalized for your having used the outcome values to choose the features.

There is no requirement that either features or outcomes need to follow a normal distribution in linear models. Some forms of inference are based on an assumption that *residuals* between observations and model predictions are distributed normally, but inference following feature selection requires extra care. See Chapter 6 of [Statistical Learning with Sparsity](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/StatLearnSparsity/) and the R [`selectiveInference` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=selectiveInference).